# What does this regular expression in Qt mean?

Tags: c++, regex, qt

What does this regex expression in Qt mean? I can't understand the meaning behind the `?=`.

`QRegularExpression functionPattern("\\b[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*(?=\\()");`

P.S.: This is a regex expression about parsing the C language function name.

Comment: Tip: Dump it into a [regex explainer](https://regex101.com).

Comment: Thanks, I figured this question out, I haven't understood the meaning of "?=" before.

Answer (score 1):

First, remember to unescape the double backward slashes `\\` into a single backslash `\`, obtaining the actual regex `\b[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*(?=\()`.

Feeding the above regex into [the debug page](https://regex101.com/r/wQFTsV/1) for this regex, we have the following:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As Nole pointed out, you should unescape the double backward slashes into a single backslash. A single backslash followed by certain characters has special meaning. E.g., `\b` means the boundary of a word and it doesn't capture anything. For example, `\bword\b` matches `word`, `something, word, something else`, but not `password`. `(?=…)` is a positive lookahead and it is a non-capturing group, i.e., it doesn't capture anything. It means that there should be `…` in that position. In our case, `(?=\()` means there should be  `(` in the position. Note that the single backslash before `(` used to mean the literal `(` and not its meaning in RegEx context, i.e., grouping.

The whole pattern means a word (and not part of a word, since we used `\b` at the beginning) that Starts with a letter or an underscore (`[A-Za-z_]`) that "may" followed by a letter, an underscore or a number (`[A-Za-z0-9_]*`; "may" refers to the `*`). And it should be followed by `(`.

Note again that this pattern captures whole the word up until the `(` and not `(` itself.